# What is the simplest way to write: if(gender == 'm' || gender == 'f')?

Tags: javascript

Is there a simpler way of writing `if(gender == 'm' || gender == 'f')`?

It would be ideal to write it as `if(gender == ('m' || 'f'))` but this won't work. What's the best method of writing this in JS or jQuery?

Comment: What worries you about the simple and obvious way you've written it already?

Comment: You could/should use `===` instead of `==`, because `gender` is a string

Comment: A **crazy** way to do it: `if (['m','f'].indexOf(gender) >= 0)`

Comment: @KhanhTO Crazier : `switch (gender) {case 'm':case 'f': SOME_JS_CODE_HERE; break; default:}`

Comment: There's a point at which a quest for "simpler" code turns into a quest for "clever code which happens to arbitrarily require fewer keystrokes."  I think you've reached that point.  Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103299/help-me-understand-this-brian-kernighan-quote

Comment: `if(gender in { m:1, f:1 })`
if gender="constructor" it also returns true

Answer (score 7):

Best method? Go with the method you have, how simpler can you make it?

```
if(gender == 'm' || gender == 'f')
```

Anything else is just going to make it harder to understand.

To allow for hermaphrodites/transgender though, go with @kamituel :)

Comment: Good bit of logic there. Nice and simple.

Comment: It's worth using strict equality operators here.

Answer (score 5):

As already stated, everyone has their own way of doing this. I, being primarily working in Lua, use this method:

```
allowed = { 'm': true, 'f': true }
if( allowed[gender] )
```

Comment: simple but elegant, +1

Comment: Interestingly elegant, I like it.  But I wouldn't say it's simpler or easier to understand than the original.  Subjective as that is.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want, you can write:

```
if ("mf".indexOf(gender) >= 0) { ...
```

But, while shorter, I don't think is more readable. Also, it'll break for `gender` === `mf` (or maybe, as suggested in the comments, it's something you might actually want).

**Edit:** also, you might want to use:

```
if(gender === 'm' || gender === 'f')
```

instead of

```
if(gender == 'm' || gender == 'f')
```

See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_when_to_use_them) why.

Comment: +1 It will work even for the third gender! It's a feature, not a bug!!! :-)

Comment: @xanatos - haven't thought of it, but yes ;)

Comment: True, this answer actually supports hermaphrodites

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (['m','f'].indexOf(gender) >= 0) {

    }
```

Comment: more elegant than my answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code you have already.

However, to appease your quest for shorter code and/or code that doesn't repeat the variable name twice:

**Option 1:** A `switch` statement.

```
switch(gender) {
    case 'm' : ....
    case 'f' : ....
}
```

(don't forget the `break` statements though)

**Option 2:** Array or string mapping:

```
var possibleGenders = ['m','f']; //or just = "mf", and use indexOf on the string, since we're dealing with a single char
if(possibleGenders.indexOf(gender) >=0) { .... }
```

**Option 3:** Regex (ewwww! don't do this):

```
if(gender.match(/^[mf]$/)) { .... }
```

**Option 4:** Use a boolean value rather than 'm' or 'f':

So rather than having a `gender` variable, have an `isMale` variable, set to `true` or `false`. This reduces the amount of code required elsewhere, such as in this `if()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (~"mf".indexOf(gender)) {
    // true
}
```

But, don't do it unless you hate your fellow developers, or want to be hated.

Comment: not totally correct : `~"mf".indexOf('')==-1`.

Comment: No, `~"mf".indexOf(gender)` will be `0`, when `"mf".indexOf(gender)` is `-1`.

Comment: Yes and `"whatever".indexOf('')` will return 0. Just try it yourself: `alert(~"mf".indexOf(''));` :)

Comment: Yeah, string's indexOf return 0 when you search for an empty string. If you want to stay kinky, you can always split('') the string into an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if(gender in { m:1, f:1 })
```

Butch watch out, if gender is "constructor" it also return true.

Comment: Or `toString` or `valueOf` or `hasOwnProperty` or... any property of `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, at least in plain javascript. If you have more than two values to compare you can always use an array (`[v1, v2, ...].indexOf(gender) != -1` in javascript, or `gender in [v1, v2, v3]` in coffeescript) but I don't feel it's worth the trouble in your case.

If you still feel such feature should exist you can always make a pull request on the coffee-script project and see what people think about it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fora dynamic number of options you can do something like this:

```
var genderOpts = ['m','f'] //or more of course
for(var genderOpt in genderOpts)
    if(gender == genderOpt)
        return true;

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(gender == 'm' || gender == 'f')
```

I think this is simple enough. The important thing is not writing just simple code, but writing simple code to be easily understood.

Comment: It is there already, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18593504/1671639